# Use WFS feed in online notebook with ogr2ogr

Tags: python, gdal, ogr2ogr

Any ideas about pulling WFS datasets into an online notebook like HEX or Deepnote? Can GDAL / ogr2ogr be run via python in an online notebook?

An example of an ogr2ogr that works on a desktop (noting this is not WFS) that would be desired in an online notebook.

Particular issue is that attempts at installing GDAL/ogr2ogr fail with dependency issues. Has anyone had success at this?

```
ogr2ogr -f KML C:\countries.kml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson --debug on --config GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL YES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR in Deepnote:

```
!apt update
!apt install -y gdal-bin
```

I have prepared an [example notebook](https://deepnote.com/workspace/deepnote-8b0ebf6d-5672-4a8b-a488-2dd220383dd3/project/org2org-example-337207ef-3b80-42ba-91b7-0bd0e17e4ba3) in Deepnote, showing GDAL installation in default Deepnote environment. Feel free to duplicate and use in your project.

More detail: I have installed the `apt` package inside of the notebook to give the most straightforward solution, but there are more elegant ways to do this, which ensure that the package is available when you start the notebook and you will no longer need the cell with `!apt update ...`. This can be done by moving the [package installation to the Dockerfile](https://deepnote.com/docs/custom-environments#local-dockerfile).

Comment: Many thanks, great demo! Seems obvious, appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Happy to hear this helped.

Comment: For what it's worth, seems there are very different implementations between notebooks. +1 for Deepnote.